# Ошибка OAuth2 (token_rejected)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, oauth2, windows-10-mobile

Проект Windows 10 UWP.

Использую библиотеку [AsyncOauth](https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth).

После неправильного ввода логина и пароля уже невозможно авторизоваться. Сначала сервер возвращает ошибку "oauth_problem=token_rejected", потом просто перестает присылать oauth_verifier

Сценарии возникновения ошибки:

- При запуске приложения ввожу правильный логин и пароль - все ОК (этот шаг можно и пропустить, ошибка возникает после первого ввода неправильных данных)
- После этого ввожу неправильные данные - ошибка авторизации.
- Потом опять правильные - oauth_problem=token_rejected
- Потом опять правильные - ошибка авторизации (в ответе перестает приходить oauth_verifier)
- После перезапуска приложения - опять все ок до первого ввода неправильных данных

В чем может быть проблема? 
Ниже код:

```
...
    using AsyncOAuth;
...
public static async Task<AccessToken> getToken(string Login, string Password)
    {
        OAuthUtility.ComputeHash = _encryptor.GetHmacHash;

        try
        {
            return await GetAccessToken(Login, Password);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

private static async Task<AccessToken> GetAccessToken(string Login, string Password)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var authorizer = new OAuthAuthorizer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            var tokenResponse = await authorizer.GetRequestToken(BuildUri("oauth/request_token").ToString());
            var requestToken = tokenResponse.Token;

            var pinRequestUrl = authorizer.BuildAuthorizeUrl(BuildUri("access").ToString(), requestToken) + "&mobile";

            using (var query = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", Login),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", Password)
                }))
            {
                using (var request = await client.PostAsync(pinRequestUrl, query))
                {
                    if (request.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Bad Auth");

                    var args = ParseQueryString(request.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString());

                       //Тут возникает ошибка, oauth_verifier код не приходит
                        string verificationCode;
                        if (args.ContainsKey("oauth_verifier"))
                            verificationCode = Uri.UnescapeDataString(args["oauth_verifier"]);
                        else
                            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Bad Auth");

                          var accessTokenResponse = await authorizer.GetAccessToken(BuildUri("oauth/access_token").ToString(), requestToken, verificationCode);
                        return accessTokenResponse.Token;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private static IDictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(string uri)
        {
            var substring = uri.Substring(((uri.LastIndexOf('?') == -1) ? 0 : uri.LastIndexOf('?') + 1));
            var pairs = substring.Trim('&', 'm', 'o', 'b', 'i', 'l', 'e').Split('&');
            return pairs.Select(piece => piece.Split('=')).ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то выдаётся?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov В описании написано oauth_problem=token_rejected, дополнил вопрос